# Unable to think about a question based on Directions in Aptitude

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am self studying quantitative aptitude and I am unable to solve this particular question.

> Question is -> Starting from Point A you fly one mile south, one mile east, then 1 mile north which brings you back to Point A. Point A is not North Pole. Then in which hemisphere you are in?

Attempt -> I assumed a starting point ( A) and then proceed for directions given in the question but the problem is that I could not say which hemisphere  I was actually in at A?

So, I can't solve this problem and need help.

Comment: If $A$ isn't the north pole, then your eastward journey must start and end at the same point.

Comment: @AnginaSeng, I am also kinda curious about this question, do you mean that you are really far south and you travel one mile south along the edge of the eastern and western hemisphere, go east for a mile which takes you back to where you were, and then go north?

Comment: @Angina Seng How it is so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are at the southern hemisphere.

As you travel south and land on point $B$, as you travel around in the east direction, you want to end up at the same point as $B$ and then travel back up. this is only posible if you are close enough to the south pole.

An explicit construction:

Consider a circle of circumference $1$ mile that is near the south pole. Let your starting point be a point above the circle by $1$ mile. As you travel down, you visit the circle and you travel along the circle and travel back up.